# Multi Curreny To product

Tags: magento2, multicurrency

We are using Magento 2 and we want to setup different currency for different product like **Product1 IN USD**, **product2 IN EURO** and **Product3 IN INR** and create a bundle product(Eg: - Bundleproduct) of all these 3 products, and when it is checked out the purchase of Invoice should be base on the Currency of the Product.

Any Help would be appricated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will be helpful for you

[Managing multiple currencies in Magento 2](http://blog.belvg.com/managing-multiple-currencies-in-magento-2.html)